# How can I get the correct type if an object property has a prefix and I only know the prefix in TS?

Tags: typescript

This one is a bit tricky to describe in words, so I will just start with the code. Let's say I have to deal with strings that have the following format:

```
type ColumnName<
  Prefix extends string,
  Period extends 'month' | 'week'
> = `${Prefix}.${Period}`;`
```

For example, `ColumnName<'dimension_date', 'month'>` would be `'dimension_date.month'`. Now let

```
type Month<Prefix extends string> = ColumnName<Prefix, 'month'>;
type Week<Prefix extends string> = ColumnName<Prefix, 'week'>;
```

Next, I have a function that takes either a `Month` or a `Week`, and a `Prefix`:

```
const get = <Prefix extends string>(
  column: Month<Prefix> | Week<Prefix>,
  prefix: Prefix
) => {
    const monthColumn: ColumnName<Prefix, 'month'> = `${prefix}.month`;

    if (column === monthColumn) {
      console.log(column); // column has type `${Prefix}.month`, as expected
    }
  };
```

This works as expected. However, I actually need `column` to be an object property:

```
type MonthObject<Prefix extends string> = { [K in Month<Prefix>]: number };
type WeekObject<Prefix extends string> = { [K in Week<Prefix>]: number };

const getObj = <Prefix extends string>(
  object: MonthObject<Prefix> | WeekObject<Prefix>,
  prefix: Prefix
) => {
  const monthColumn: ColumnName<Prefix, 'month'> = `${prefix}.month`;

  if (monthColumn in object) {
    console.log(object); // object has type MonthObject<Prefix> | WeekObject<Prefix>, while it expect it to only have type MonthObject<Prefix>.
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make typescript understand that inside of the if statement the type can only be `MonthObject<Prefix>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to assert the type.

```
const isMonth = 
    <Prefix extends string>(obj: MonthObject<Prefix> | WeekObject<Prefix>, prefix: Prefix)
        : obj is MonthObject<Prefix> => {
            const monthColumn: ColumnName<Prefix, 'month'> = `${prefix}.month`;
            return monthColumn in obj
}
```

And use this function as the condition.

```
const getObj = <Prefix extends string>(
  object: MonthObject<Prefix> | WeekObject<Prefix>,
  prefix: Prefix
) => {
  if (isMonth(object, prefix)) {
    console.log(object);
    //          ^? (parameter) object: MonthObject<Prefix>

  }
}
```

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2A5AhiiAeAKCigAUAnCAMwEsAPKCW4CNAEwGcp3gzq0BzADRFSEXnFYMmLDlADkKOGmAALOVAA+8gO4QIAazkEAfFAC8UAAYASAN7kqdAL4A6OyTHUJTywG4CBKCQUACySqp4DjT0jMxsnNy8AqYW8Mjo2LiRFNGC8orKasb+QdAA6nr62Y4x0vFcPHz8KbCIqJg4+FF0eXK6BnLFAQDGStxQ-BDA5lDV0VJxsolNxgAUIqPpaABcoeEqc3SmWhUGh7TGwsRgOXS73bQEAJTmprYixKNo4wWqae27f4ZTrnXq-IozGy2G41VzgvwfKDUShQVabdrmMwWcFAtAvd7EQlQL7sRAQFwIOD8NFtdBPXxQAD0jOJtLQUBUWE4pSs7lutDh+0seS5Ukgw2YrERTgITn8gXA0DChQA8gAjABWEAl5wWMgSjWSM1sUAA2gBpJHs5URB7GAC6uzQqDVYigcoVwVO+nVWp1Dz19WWRosJotVqg3vODqdLrdHoIJOm1HYNpUM0Ruti+oaSWaqzgmt2ad92uA0c0kcqpf9-MuUBh0Xu-KeiKJu0LGqRnBLmrLFbMbzbRMJSagOLZgLZmS6-LB+0GkLsjecLnh-hHm6gFGASDI7InWwjndlIzG00mwF9MyzdSWhvzIk7ZeL+xr5btle97+jVwb-ObGpnleKACSRFFVhTNMCz7CU8hXWgnnxRESTJCkqRgv1gHpRFmS3QkAD0AH4RBlJwgA)